# GLFW: glfwSetGammaRamp function not working

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

calling glfwSetGammaRamp not making any effect on version 3.3.2, however, I remember it used to work in the previous version.
I tried to run the code on the other monitor but it didn't work as well.

```
#include "GLFW/glfw3.h"

int main()
{
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    int count;
    GLFWmonitor ** m = glfwGetMonitors(&count);

    GLFWwindow * win = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello Pointers", NULL, NULL);

    GLFWgammaramp ramp;
    unsigned short red[256], green[256], blue[256];

    ramp.size = 256;
    ramp.red = red;
    ramp.green = green;
    ramp.blue = blue;

    for (int i = 0; i < ramp.size; i++)
        ramp.red[i] = ramp.green[i] = ramp.blue[i] = 75;

    glfwSetGammaRamp(monitor, &ramp);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(win))
    {
        glfwSwapBuffers(win);

        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();

    return 0
}
```

Comment: Does it work on an actual (modechange'd, not borderless/windowed fullscreen) fullscreen window?

Comment: @genpfault I tried all options but no luck. The Command that is working is ```glfwSetGamma(float gamma)``` but this is not good enough because it only controls the screen darkness. while in  ```glfwSetGammaRamp(monitor, &ramp)``` you could change the color.